# Inserting images in JEditorPane using pane.getDocument.insert()

Tags: java, image, swing, jeditorpane

I am creating a chat application and I want to append strings into JEditorPane, so I am using JEditorPane.getDocument.insert() method to do this:

```
clientListDoc.insertString(clientListDoc.getLength(),image+"-"+name[0]+"\n", null);
```

But now I also want to display images. I have set the content type to HTML and I use this:

```
String temp=ClassLoader.getSystemResource("images/away.png").toString();
image="<img src='"+temp+"'></img>";
```

But I don't get images on JEditorPane if I use insert() but when I use setText() images are displayed. Please help!! I want to do both these things!

One approach I though could be to use getText to get the previous strings and append the new string to this string and then use setText() to set the entire string but is there a better solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `setText()` method, it is being formated to HTML for you. With `insertString`, your markups are converted to text. Look at the source HTML of your document, you'll see that **< img src=imagepath >** will be **& lt;img src=imagepath & gt;**.

You'll need to use HTMLDocument class to insert your image properly:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JEditorPane edPane = new JEditorPane(); 

        try {

            edPane.setContentType("text/html");

            System.out.println(edPane.getText());

            HTMLEditorKit hek = new HTMLEditorKit();

            edPane.setEditorKit(hek);

            HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) edPane.getDocument();

            doc.insertString(0, "Test testing", null);

            Element[] roots = doc.getRootElements();
            Element body = null;
            for( int i = 0; i < roots[0].getElementCount(); i++ ) {
                Element element = roots[0].getElement( i );
                if( element.getAttributes().getAttribute( StyleConstants.NameAttribute ) == HTML.Tag.BODY ) {
                    body = element;
                    break;
                }
            }

            doc.insertAfterEnd(body,"<img src="+ClassLoader.getSystemResource("thumbnail.png").toString()+">");
            System.out.println(edPane.getText());
        } catch(BadLocationException e) {
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {}


        frame.add(edPane);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Comment: Format it with inline css or html.

Comment: You rOcK! I am so happy :)!